# React router routes don't match location

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Unsure why this isn't working? Everything has been imported correctly so am unsure why I get the following error message in the console:

> No routes matched location "/"

App.jsx

```
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import Explore from './pages/Explore';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, useRoutes} from "react-router-dom";
// import { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  let routes = useRoutes([
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" exact element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/explore" exact element={<Explore />}/>
      </Routes>
  ])
  return routes;
}

const AppWrapper = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  );
};

export default AppWrapper;
```

And the Home file

```
import React from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const Home = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    return (
        
        <div>
            <div>
                <button onClick={() => {navigate("/explore");}}>  
                    Explore page
                </button>
                <h1>Home page</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation of `useRoutes()` from [here](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#useroutes), you're using the hook in an incorrect manner.

You can use the traditional way of doing routing with `react-router-dom`, as follows:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" exact element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/explore" exact element={<Explore />} />
    </Routes>
  )
}

const AppWrapper = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  )
}
```

If you really want to use `useRoutes`, I encourage you to look into the example sent in the link from above.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. ❤️. I will check out that link now.

Comment: If the answer solved your issue consider ticking the answer such that people could see that this solves the issue.

Comment: Thanks Marius. I'm new to stack overflow, I've just ticked it.

Answer (score 0):

The `useRoutes` hook takes a routes configuration ***object***. Your code is passing JSX. This is an invalid use of the `useRoutes` hook.

[useRoutes](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#useroutes)

The two methods for rendering routes:

1. Use the `useRoutes` hook with routes configuration object.

   ```
   const routesConfig = [
     {
       path: "/",
       element: <Home />
     },
     {
       path: "/explore",
       element: <Explore />
     },
   ];

   const App = () => {
     const routes = useRoutes(routesConfig);
     return routes;
   };
   ```
2. Render the JSX directly.

   ```
   const App = () => {
     return (
       <Routes>
         <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
         <Route path="/explore" element={<Explore />}/>
       </Routes>
     );
   };
   ```